# substitute column names of with file names of corresponding file in a folder

Tags: r, filenames, substitution

I have 200 files in one folder looks like chin01.txt, chin02.txt ect. each read.table of each .txt file produce a n rows by 2 column data frame with column and row names.

now I want to change the first column name of each data frame to corresponding file name, such as chi001, what I should do? below are my first lines of codes:

```
files_all <- list.files(path="D:\R\C_test", pattern="*.txt", full.names=T, recursive=FALSE)

for (currentFile in files_all){
  file <- read.table(currentFile, header=F)
  columnames(file) <- c(**name of currentFile such as chin001**,"depth")
  write.table(file, file=sub(pattern=".txt$", replacement="_new.txt", x=currentFile),sep="\t", quote=F, row.names=T, col.names=T)
}
```

but I don't know how to write **name of currentFile such as chin001** part, thank you for any reply

Answer (score 1):

Remove the .txt part from the filename (there are plenty of ways of doing this) then replace the first column name with that name.

```
currentFile <- sub(".txt", "", file) # file could be e.g. filename.txt
names(file)[1] <- currentFile
```